# Como poner un hilo en un JtextArea

Tags: java, poo, interfaz-gráfica, herencia, interface

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en Java con intefaz gráfica y hilos resulta que cree una clase llamada animal en mi proyecto en donde tengo el hilo pero resulta en el formulario quiero que este hilo no se vea por consola sino en el Jtextarea para lo cual tengo 3 botones un boton que debe de iniciar otro de pausar y por ultimo el de salir que ya lo tengo implementado , acontinuacion les adjunto un capture de mi programa .
[image: Aqui pueden ver lo que tengo hasta ahora]

[image: introducir el código aquí]

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
      Liebre = new Animal (1,"Liebre");
      Tortuga = new Animal (5,"Tortuga");
     
       Thread L,T;
   
       L = new Thread(Liebre);
       T = new Thread(Tortuga);
       
       L.start();
       T.start();
       jTextArea1.append(L.toString());
       jTextArea1.append(T.toString());
    }
```

Clase con el hilo Animal

```
public class Animal implements Runnable {
    String cadena;
      int veloc;

   public Animal(int velocidad,String nombre)
    {
     cadena = nombre;
      veloc = velocidad;

    }

    public void run()
    {
     for(int i=0;i < 10;++i)
     {
            
      System.out.print(cadena);
      try{
           Thread.sleep(1000/veloc);
         }catch(Exception e){;}
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + cadena + "ha llegado");
    return;

    }
}
```

Comment: Quieres que lo que imprimes en consola en el metodo run del hilo que creaste aparezca en el JTextArea?, ¿Que has intentado hacer para conseguirlo?, deberías ponerlo en la pregunta.

Comment: si amigo eso es si me puedes ayudar con eso

Comment: No puedo ver el código en las imagenes, saludos

Comment: Hola amiga ya lo voy a adjuntar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es una interfaz para mensajería. Implementarla en el formulario y consumirla en el hilo.

```
interface Mensajero {
    public void darMensaje(String mensaje);
}

public class Formulario extends JFrame implements Mensajero {
    //...

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        Liebre = new Animal (1,"Liebre", this);
        Tortuga = new Animal (5,"Tortuga", this);
 
        Thread L, T;

        L = new Thread(Liebre);
        T = new Thread(Tortuga);
   
        L.start();
        T.start();
        jTextArea1.append(L.toString());
        jTextArea1.append(T.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void darMensaje(String mensaje){
        jTextArea1.append(mensaje);
    }
}

public class Animal implements Runnable {
    String cadena;
    int veloc;
    Mensajero mensajero;

    public Animal(int velocidad,String nombre, Mensajero mens) {
        cadena = nombre;
        veloc = velocidad;
        mensajero = mens;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i < 10;++i) {
        
            //System.out.print(cadena);
            mensajero.darMensaje(cadena);

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000/veloc);
            } 
            catch(Exception e) {}
        }

        //System.out.println("\n" + cadena + "ha llegado");
        mensajero.darMensaje("\n" + cadena + "ha llegado");

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo